# Array of objects to json

Tags: javascript, json

I don't know if there is a related question but I have a variable with the following structure:

```
[
  { key_1: [{...},{...},{...}] },
  { key_2: [{...},{...},{...}] },
  { key_3: [{...},{...},{...}] },
]
```

I want to achieve this:

```
[
  { 
    key_1: [{...},{...},{...}],
    key_2: [{...},{...},{...}],
    key_3: [{...},{...},{...}]
  }
]
```

I've tried doing things with `map`and `forEach` but I'm really stuck. Thanks for your help

Comment: can you add some of the things that you have tried?

Comment: The question is answered but I was doing a stupidity. Literally the same code as the accepted answer but I was using `const` instead of `let` and the error level was unchecked in the console, so I wasn't able to see what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let output = {};

array.forEach(doc => {
    for(let key in doc){
        output[key] = doc[key];
    }
});

let result = [output]
```

Answer (score 4):

A more compact version that does not require multiple forEach calls might be something like this:

```
const final = [initial.reduce((finalObj, nextObj) => Object.assign(finalObj, nextObj), {})]
```

This uses reduce to start off with a new object and then Object.assign() to merge each of the inner objects into it.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. What this does is iterate through all elements in the initial array, then goes through all the keys in that object. It'll copy over all those into the `result` object.

```
let result = {};

initial.forEach(obj =>
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => result[key] = obj[key])
);
```

Comment: This works too, but [@mickl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6238977/mickl) answeres first so I'm accepting his answer. But hey, thank you!

Comment: All good! Was just making sure that it worked, otherwise I definitely would have had it in first (not that it much matters)